# Using a half-space as a big mark for knitr output

Tags: r, escaping, knitr

I would like a number like `50000` to be printed in a knitr document with a half-space as a thousands separator. In LaTeX I would just use `50\,000`, and I would like knitr to print this via a `Sexpr` command. That is, I would like a function `reformat` which when used in the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
num <- 50000
@

The number is \Sexpr{reformat(num)}.

\end{document}
```

Prints 50 000 with a half space. The problem I face is that using `formatC` doesn't seem to allow the correct number of backslashes

```
formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\,")
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\,"

formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\\,")
[1] "50,000.0000"

formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\\\,")
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\\,"
```

What's the correct function in place of `reformat`?

Comment: Try `formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\u2009")` (though for some reason it prints a full space in my R console).

Comment: maybe try the formatting options of the siunitx package (latex)?

Comment: the rule is to keep adding backslashes until it works; here you need 4: `cat(formatC(50000, format = "f", big.mark = "\\\\,"))`, as suggested by `?formatC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Roland and baptiste's solutions work fine:

```
reformat <- function(num) formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\\\\,")
reformat <- function(num) formatC(num, format = "f", big.mark = "\u2009")
```